# Where to get the tools.jar to use with the Java 8 jdk early release

Tags: java, java-8

Where to get tools.jar for Java 8 JDK early release? Without it, my Java 1.8 Maven pom based projects in Netbeans will not compile.

The Java 8 early release is set in the Java Platforms setting and all the Java 8 projects that are not Maven-based will compile and run.

https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

It is not found on the downloads page, I can not find anything in their search.

Does anyone have success compiling Maven pom based projects with the Java 8 early release?

Can the old `tools.jar` be used or where did you find it?

Comment: It's in the JDK. You didn't accidentally download the JRE did you? There are several questions in a similar vein on this site that mention the same issue

Comment: @Petesh I had the JDK from early in October (JDK, not JRE) and I verified it is not there. I just reinstalled the JDK from the most recent version and it is there.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. You are not allowed to add answers in the body of the question. If you found an alternative solution then please add it in the space below where all the other answers go.

Comment: The age of the question has nothing to do with it. You should not have put it there in the first place. If this is a clarification of the problem then you should remove the big ANSWER part. It is confusing. However, it doesn't look as a clarification, it looks like a solution in which case it invalidates the question and should be removed. If you want to keep it then add it as an answer below. That's how Q&A sites work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer on the behalf of question author:

> This version is missing `tools.jar`:
> `jdk-8-ea-bin-b106-windows-i586-05_sep_2013.exe`
>
> It is now in the most recent release.

Comment: This  q/a is being discussed in the [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404191/are-m)

Comment: I purposely put the answer in the original question because Oracle accidentally omitted `tools.jar` from the exe install file for *only/just that version*. This is very unexpected!  I would not expect others to read this page and digest all the various answers to find out why it is missing. The most immediate thing tome was to present the unexpected answer. That is why. I only wanted to save people from digesting this entire page to fix this bug. Of course, there is nothing wrong with other answers. However, I wanted to curate the primary issue, i.e., *Oracle forgot to bundle it in the exe.*

Comment: I would suggest that if the issue only appears in a specific release, then either 1. information about the specific release should appear in the question (which it may be; I don't think I am familiar enough with Java to definitely exclude the possibility), or 2. the answer should be better phrased as something like "If you are using version `X`, version `X` was missing `tools.jar`. This has been fixed in later versions / from version `Y`. I think 2 is the better option here, so as not to invalidate all the other answers.

Answer (score 18):

The `tools.jar` file on the 1.8.0 JDK is located in `jdk1.8.0/lib/tools.jar`. If it's not there, then you don't have the JDK installed correctly.

Please see the accepted answer - the `tools.jar` file was omitted in a specific early access revision (`jdk-8-ea-bin-b106-windows-i586-05_sep_2013.exe`).

Comment: In my jdk1.8.0_102 it's not there any more.

Comment: Details are important when you make mention of 'it not being there any more' - what platform, exactly what version, how did you install it, etc… I'm looking at the i686 version of java installed on windows and it has tools.jar in `c:/program files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_102/lib/tools.jar`

Comment: See 'Answer on the behalf of OP' below. Basically, Oracle didn't bundle it in certain versions - seemingly by accident.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to install devel package. On RHEL family it's like this:

```
# yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Comment: Crazy that you need to install an additional devel package for the open Java *Development* Kit to work.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem when using Hadoop-Common-2.7.2 as a dependency. I resolved the problem by adding the following exclusions to my `POM.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. But for future reference, if tools.jar is needed, where do I get it from? It is not in my java\jdk-14.0.1\lib or bin folders.

Comment: It should be in that folder, if it's not you might have installed wrong version or corrupted version. In windows it will be in c:/Prog~File@~/java/JDK ~/lib folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can download any version of the `tools.jar` file. For example, it is available from [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/t/Downloadtools160jar.htm). It would be preferable, though, to find it on the official Oracle site, if possible.

After downloading any version of the `tools-x.x.jar` file, simply rename it to `tools.jar` (removing the version number) and place it in the `jrex.x/lib` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Some JDK packages contain just the Java Runtime Environment.

So for instance in **Fedora, Oracle Linux, RHEL, CentOS** `java-1.8.0-openjdk` package contains just the JRE. If you want the development tools, then install the `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` package instead.

And in **Debian/Ubuntu** `openjdk-8-jre` package contains just the JRE. If you want the development tools, then install the `openjdk-8-jdk` package instead.

Answer (score 2):

The file `tools.jar` was removed in Java 9. Please see "Removed Tools and Components" on Oracle.com JDK 9 page [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#GUID-12237744-E23B-42F8-8892-26BA1BDD63F2)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found the solution in the Android Public Issue Tracker: [tools.jar not packed in lib of Java JDK 8 and Android studio gives tools.jar missing error](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187048).

As kn...@gmail.com states in [comment #8](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37062313#comment8), the error appears only when the JDK is not installed in its default directory. The problem is resolved by reinstalling the JDK into its default directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you look into the folder
`C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_version/lib` 
instead of 
`C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_version/lib`

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at `Eclipse > Window > preference > Java > Installed JRE >`, it was pointing to `JRE`, which seems obvious. However, when I changed it to point to `JDK`, the compile error was resolved. This is because there is `tools.jar` in the  `JDK` folder.

Before this, I had tried copying `tools.jar` from `jdk/lib` to `jre/lib`. However, that did not solve the issue.

Comment: I tried changing JRE to JDK, I do have tools.jar in jdk. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221. But it does not work - eclipse somehow keeps pointing to the JRE folder. **I applied and restarted eclipse.**

Comment: My JAVA_HOME also point to jdk (since begining). Eclipse keeps giving this tools.jar error. Added the STS plugin but Spring does not show up in the  New project list. I guess it is related to this tools.jar. The jre list in eclipse itself points to the jdk folder, does not show tools.jar in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the `tools.jar` from your `jdk\lib` folder and paste into `jre\lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update the `eclipse.ini` file. If no JDK is used for Eclipse, change it:

- Quit Eclipse if it is running
- Go to the Eclipse installation directory and open the file `eclipse.ini` in a text editor
- Search for the line `-vmargs`
- Before the line `-vmargs`, add two lines:

  - On the first line, write `-vm`
  - On the second line, write the path to your JDK installation (usually something like: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\javaw.exe` on Windows)*

[Solution also documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662394/missing-tools-jar-when-launching-sts-application)

Answer (score 0):

If using Reactive Native:

1. Install the latest JDK from [here](https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).
2. If the problem not solved then go back to react-native documentation about installing react native (android) on mac, [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/_getting-started-macos-android#installing-dependencies)
3. In root of your reactnative project:

   ```
   cd android
   ./gradlew clean 
   ./gradlew assembleRelease
   ```