# ant -version results in missing tools.jar file error

Tags: java, ant

I'm new in the ant world and have run into an issue involving the missing tools.jar file when I perform the ant -version command from a cmd prompt.  I've reviewed most of the other postings and have not found a solution.
I have installed jdk-8u60-windows-i586, and apache-ant-1.9.6. (the installations were done in this order)
The Path includes both ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME variables
ANT_HOME is set to the location folder where apache-ant is located
JAVA_HOME is set to the location folder where the jdk is installed
I've run a system scan for tools.jar and was unable to locate it

Comment: It's not the same issue.  I didn't download the JRE files by mistake so the post noted does not solve my issue.

Comment: What is JAVA_HOME set to?

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set to the E:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60

Comment: I found this article:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722058/where-to-get-the-tools-jar-to-use-with-the-java-8-jdk-early-release which indicated that if I don't find the tools.jar file in the JDK lib folder that the install was unsuccessful.  I reinstalled the JDK and the file is now in the correct location.  I then did an ant -version command at the command prompt and got the expected results.