# interest thing that the latest versions of JDK doesn't include the tools.jar and where to find it

Tags: java, gradle

i was looking for the tools.jar since my gradle point me that these file is missing, so i searched over here for some results, all of the results point that i need to make a new PATH to JAVA_HOME something i already have in my variables , [one result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722058/where-to-get-the-tools-jar-to-use-with-the-java-8-jdk-early-release/38528448) point out that at the latest version of JDK the file is missing, so my question is, is there any replace for these issue? when i download JDK it does not include the file , also the JRE (latest versions), so only to go back?

Comment: The stuff, or at least some of the stuff, inside `tools.jar` got moved into `jdk.*` modules (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/index.html)).

Comment: @Slaw so when i point the Gradle to the jdk i got error missing file, how is that?
[img1](https://i.imgur.com/ylqK5Kz.jpg)
[img2](https://i.imgur.com/b8e9MJL.jpg)
[img3](https://i.imgur.com/7Q86bgv.jpg)

Comment: Not sure what exactly is wrong with your setup, but: (1) Make sure you're using a Gradle version compatible with the Java version. (2) Make sure you're using the correct Java version. The Gradle error indicates it's trying to use a JRE-8u202 installation; I don't believe `tools.jar` is present in JREs, only the JDK (for version 8 and below).

Comment: @Slaw i'm using the latest version of gradle download from the site,
[img] (https://imgur.com/xrKATVe)
these is my versions, according to the oracle site these is the latest [version](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)

Comment: @Slaw if i will uninstall the JRE , i will stay with jdk, it will help? than still i will need the tools file isn't it?